# C# HttpClient refresh token strategy

Tags: c#, httpclient, delegatinghandler

Since Microsoft [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7) that the `HttpClient` be created once and reused throughout the life of a program, I wondering how to update `DefaultRequestHeaders` when for example, the token has expired and need to be refresh.

`DefaultRequestHeaders` is more over not thread safe (for what I know) and the list of headers defined there, shared by all potentially pending requests. `Clear()` the list and `Add()` the header with a new token, seems not the wise thing to do.

---

#### Update

To be more precise, I don't want/need to change request headers for every request. Only when I've got a HTTP 401 status code.

Comment: Don't use the helper methods, build an `HttpRequestMessage` and use `SendAsync` instead.

Comment: Thinking about it, you could maybe write an HttpClientHandler that automatically adds headers depending on where the request is going.

Comment: @john Use `SendAsync` or `HttpClientHandler` will not help to change header **only** when authorization fails after a token has expired for example. Besides a `DelegatingHandler` as pointed out by @brennan-mann seems more appropriate

Comment: In the code sample below, there is a message handler that looks at the response. You could look at the HttpStatus and check for a 401 response,  update your token and resubmit. Does your token have an expiration  or time to live property that you can check before sending the request?

Comment: @PhilippeLécaillon I wasn't talking about changing the header, I was talking about moving away from `DefaultRequestHeaders` altogether. I see brennan went with my second idea :)

Comment: @BrennanMann No TTL or expiredIn property in my 'not so a token in fact' :) But implement a `DelegatingHandler` that requests a *token* when the `base.SendAsync()` fails with a 401 status is the way I'll go. I'll update my post with an example when I can. Thx

Comment: Microsoft's current recommendation, as of mid-2019, in ASP.NET Core web-applications is to use `IHttpClientFactory` (which maintains a long-life'd pool of host platform-specific `HttpMessageHandler` instances) to create short-life'd `HttpClient` objects. This approach is not necessarily applicable to desktop and mobile applications, however and a singleton `HttpClient` _may_ be more appropriate. YMMV.

Answer (score 7):

Wire up a message handler with your HttpClient when you register the IHttpClient in the DI container registry phase or use another pattern such as a factory or singleton to return an instance of the IHttpClient with a custom message handler. Inspect the outbound call and add the necessary headers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/httpclient-message-handlers

**Sample header message handler**

```
class MessageHandler1 : DelegatingHandler
    {


    private int _count = 0;

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
        request.Headers.Add("X-Custom-Header", _count.ToString());
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**Sample logger message handler:**

```
class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler

{
    StreamWriter _writer;

public LoggingHandler(Stream stream)
{
    _writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
}

protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        _writer.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", request.RequestUri, 
            (int)response.StatusCode, response.Headers.Date);
    }
    return response;
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        _writer.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

}

**Add it to the pipeline**

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new Handler1(), new Handler2(), new Handler3());
```

**Threading Concerns**

Regarding threading concerns or concurrency, the `HttpRequestMessage` parameter on the `SendAsync` method will be per request. If you add the header to the `request.Headers` collection, you will updating headers for that instance of the request only (i.e., not globally )

Or use the Authorization property on the `request.Headers` instance:

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", bearerToken);
```

Please see MSDN link below

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage

If you use `DefaultRequestHeaders` on a static, shared, singleton, Lifestyle.Singleton, etc, instance of the HttpClient then you will have threading concerns and need proper synchronization to update the `DefaultRequestHeaders` collection.